# Docker can't create conda virtual environment

Tags: python, docker, conda

I'm trying to dockerize a python application, using conda for package management.

I generated a specfile using:

```
conda list --explicit > spec-file.txt
```

I have the following code in my Dockerfile:

```
FROM conda/miniconda3

RUN conda create -n env --file ./spec-file.txt
RUN echo "source activate env" > ~/.bashrc
ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/env/bin:$PATH
```

When I run `docker-compose build`, it produced the following error:

```
CondaFileIOError: './spec-file.txt'. [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './spec-file.txt'
```

The Dockerfile and the specfile are both in the same directory. I've tried using absolute paths and that didn't work either.

Comment: Just modify the command to `RUN conda create -n env --file spec-file.txt`

Comment: That still causes the same problem

Comment: You're not `COPY`ing the `spec-file.txt` in, so its not in the image.  The `.bashrc` setup will be ineffective (many typical paths to run Docker containers don't run a shell at all, much less a login shell) and you might want to use `ENV` statements to manually do the virtual environment setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to add the line:

```
COPY ./spec-file.txt .
```

Before trying to create the environment.